# Why have I different results beween profiling List and Generator?

Tags: python, performance, generator

I am working on a python function on graphs, that is recursive and NP complex. However, I had results in very long time, so I used kernprof to see which lines take the more time.

I saw that this line was taking more time that what I thought :

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
...
    53    120244     740797.0      6.2     17.0             if any( [m[passed].get(i, False) for passed in isom] ): # si ce noeud est lié à un noeud passé, le tester
```

So I choose to use a generator, because it seems that I should not generate all the list as I'm just interested if any is true.

But with a generator, I have this result :

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
...
    53     35283     509901.0     14.5     12.8             if any( (m[passed].get(i, False) for passed in isom) ): # si ce noeud est lié à un noeud passé, le tester
```

So it's seems that it's faster than with list comprehension, but I don't understand why the time per hit is bigger, and why I have much less hits ?

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ of rkern (https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) answer to that :

> > Why do my list comprehensions have so many hits when I use the LineProfiler?
>
> LineProfiler records the line with the list comprehension once for each iteration of the list comprehension.

And that explain I think why the time per hit is higher with generator, as in with list a lot of hits are just iteration that return false, but with generator much hits are for the generation of the generator, which is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're not comparing oranges to oranges.

The hits on the list comprehension seems to count the items in the list.  Because you are actually producing a list and only applying any() to the resulting object, you will systematically iterate through all elements of isom (hence the high number of hits).

The iterator will not go through all the elements of isom.  So the number of hits will vary depending on the density of the graph but will generally be much lower than the list comprehension (which always produces the worst case)

As for the time per hit, your total time is only smaller by a fraction (because of other overhead) but your hit count is smaller by an order of magnitude so the time per hit ratio will naturally be higher.  That ratio is not actually measuring the difference between iterator and list comprehension because the hits are not calculated on the same basis.   In order to have a meaningful comparison you would have to use a common divisor (ideally the actual number of times the line is executed).   If you compare the time per hit on the basis of the original hit count (i.e. total time for same amount of work 509901.0/120244) then the iterator's "per hit" would be 4.2